How to filter data with sequences missing sections of a specified size or greater?
I have a data frame with a sequence (Slice) of observations for each group. Many of the sequences are incomplete. This is a simplified version of the data:



Slice
GroupID
Observation




1
A
1


2
A
6


3
A
8


4
A
2


5
A
1


6
A
6


7
A
4


8
A
2


1
B
1


3
B
8


4
B
2


6
B
6


8
B
2


4
C
2


5
C
1


6
C
6


7
C
4


8
C
2



Group A has a complete sequence of observations (1-8), but groups B and C are both missing 3 observations, but group Bs missing observations are interspersed, while group Cs missing observations are in a large clump. I would like to filter out groups where 2 or more observations in a row are missing (i.e., just group C).
I've attempted the following to ID gap sizes, with the idea that I can then filter out the rows with gap sizes above a certain threshold.
df <- df %>%
  group_by(GroupID) %>%
  mutate(slice_diff = Slice - lag(Slice))

However, this does not ID gaps at the start or end of the sequence (as is the case for Group C). How would I modify this to ID gaps at the start or end of the sequence.

If you know you have 1-8 slices per group, and these are numbered as such and in order, then you can use something like df |> filter(all(diff(c(0, Slice, 9)) <= 2), .by = GroupID).

I was thinking along these lines. How would I go about manually adding  "0" and "9" Slice values for each group into the data frame so I can then use my above plan (calculate slice_diff)? I'd like to do some quick data visualization to confirm what size gaps I want to filter out in my real data


How would I go about manually adding "0" and "9" Slice values for each
group into the data frame so I can then use my above plan (calculate
slice_diff)?

You can have gaps at the beginning or end of the slice, so you need to determine these first. Then you can summarise by GroupID. I've added another group "D" which has a gap at the end.
df <- bind_rows(df, data.frame(Slice=1:3, GroupID="D", Observation=c(3,9,7)))
df
   Slice GroupID Observation
1      1       A           1
...
18     8       C           2
19     1       D           3
20     2       D           9
21     3       D           7


Then use the lag and lead functions with defaults of 1 and 8 to create the gaps from the starts and ends, respectively, and summarise.
mutate(df, 
      slice_lag  = ifelse(Slice<max(Slice), Slice-lag(Slice, default=1), 0),
      slice_lead = ifelse(Slice>min(Slice), lead(Slice, default=8)-Slice, 0), 
             .by = GroupID) |>
summarise(slice_diff  = max(slice_lag, slice_lead), 
             .by = GroupID)


  GroupID slice_diff
1       A          1
2       B          2
3       C          3
4       D          5


Assuming your Slices are numeric and starting with 1 as shown, you could prepend 0 and calculate differences; negate a check if any exceed 2 in groups, using ave, and subset.
> subset(df, !ave(Slice, GroupID, FUN=\(x) any(diff(c(0, x)) > 2)))
   Slice GroupID Observation
1      1       A           1
2      2       A           6
3      3       A           8
4      4       A           2
5      5       A           1
6      6       A           6
7      7       A           4
8      8       A           2
9      1       B           1
10     3       B           8
11     4       B           2
12     6       B           6
13     8       B           2


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Slice = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), GroupID = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), Observation = c(1L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
8L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

